# In SSRS Report Manager, can report's events (i.e. Onload) be intercepted to redirect to a different URL?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In SSRS, are there events that can be intercepted (i.e. OnLoad())) so that a custom code function will execute automatically?

I have a report that is being moved to a different SSRS server and want to redirect the user to the new location if they try to open it on the old server.  Linked Reports don't work because they only apply to the SSRS instance in question.

I found some references to using JavaScript but I think that is referring to the use of the ReportViewer control within a webpage.  I have users navigating the reports in Report Manager.

We currently have SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks!

Comment: I would uninstall the SSRS service and do this with IIS, simply redirect 404's from your ReportServer directory to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

please try this way you may get it

```
function() {

        var onLoad = function() {
           // Do something...
        };
        var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");

        setTimeout(function() {
            var loading = viewerReference.get_isLoading(URL);

            if (!loading) onLoad(); 
        },100);

    })();
```

Comment: code is the only portion of an answer that should be formatted as code ... suggested an edit. Please use the format feature appropriately.